# FileWriter only displays the last line

Tags: java, filewriter

When I display the variable data using `System.out.println(data)`, it displays the content (all lines) of the "filename.txt".
However, when I use `myWriter.write(data)`, it only writes the last line of the initial file.
My task is to read a file (in this case, `filename.txt`) and copy its content into a new file (`new.txt`).

```java
package javaapplication13;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class readFile {
    public static String data;
     
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        try{
            File myObj = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication13\\src\\javaapplication13\\filename.txt");
            try (Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj)) { 
                do{ 
                     data = myReader.nextLine();   
                }
                while (myReader.hasNextLine());
 
                  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication13\\src\\javaapplication13\\new.txt");
                  FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication13\\src\\javaapplication13\\new.txt");
                  myWriter.write(data);
                   
                  myWriter.close();
                  out.close();
                  myReader.close();
  
            } 
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create with the two argument constructor [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,boolean)) with `append=true;` otherwise you're overwritting the file each time.

Comment: `do{ data = myReader.nextLine(); } while (myReader.hasNextLine());` what do you think that code does? What makes you think so?

Answer (score 1):

Every iteration of the loop opens a new writer, and then writes to it, thus overwriting the file. Instead, you should open the writer once, before the loop, and close it once you're done writing. E.g.:

```java
try (FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication13\\src\\javaapplication13\\new.txt")) {
    while (myReader.hasNextLine());
        myWriter.write(myReader.nextLine());
    } 
}
```

Comment: I tried this but sadly i don't know why it displays the same result... Thanks anyways !!

Comment: @Pshemo d'oh! you're right of course. Edited and fixed.